# Apache Storm Hbase version compatibility, java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HBASE_CLIENT_PREFETCH_LIMIT

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-storm

I'm running the following Storm setup (on Ubuntu 16.4 64 bits).

- Storm: 0.10.1
- Hadoop: 2.5.2  (local pseudo cluster)
- Hbase: 1.1.5   (local pseudo cluster)
- Compiler for the jar: maven
- Using the default hbase storm support classes via import function:       org.apache.storm.hbase.bolt.HbaseBolt and mapper.SimpleHBaseMapper.

I'm trying to write with a "Hbase" bolt towards the Hbase DB. During the process I get the following error:

```
016-07-30 21:06:14.874 b.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HBASE_CLIENT_PREFETCH_LIMIT
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionKey.<clinit>(HConnectionKey.java:42) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:271) ~[stormjar.j
ar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:197) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:159) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.hbase.common.HBaseClient$1.run(HBaseClient.java:45) ~[storm-hbase-0.10.1.jar:0.10.1]
    at org.apache.storm.hbase.common.HBaseClient$1.run(HBaseClient.java:42) ~[storm-hbase-0.10.1.jar:0.10.1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
```

This looks like a similar issue: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/CIS-CMMI-3-HBASE-CLIENT-PREFETCH-LIMIT-td4254588.html  which outcomes in a compatibility issue.

In the provided storm-hbase jar I can see references made to:
hbase 0.98.4-hadoop2 and hdfs version 2.2.0 but in I saw in the pom file of the supported hbase source https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-hbase that Hbase version 1.1.0 is supported.

Will my setup only work if I will switch back my Hbase version to 0.98.4-hadoop or higher till version hbase-0.98.20-hadoop2 or use the 1.1.0? Going back from 1.1.5 to 1.1.0 seems odd though and I already downgraded both. Or should I make use of the apache.hadoop.hbase classes? I save seen a lot of code making use of these classes.

Anyways, please advise. I have been troubleshooting for the past 5 days without any process.

Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: Somebody has any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the version of hbase-client in your pom differing from the jar versions on the server side.  If you're using vendor-specific versions (e.g. 1.2.0-cdh5.7.0), then that needs to be consistent as well.